# Command runs from terminal without error but fails from bash script

Tags: bash, go

Below command runs without any error from terminal but fails from bash script.

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags="-X main.level=info" cmd/adapter/*
```

My bash script is as shown below :-

```
#!/bin/bash

export GO=/usr/local/go/bin/go
export ldflags="-ldflags=\"-X main.level=info\""

CMD="$GO build -o bin/adapter $ldflags cmd/adapter/*"
echo $CMD
${CMD}
```

Bash debug using `"bash -x"` produces following output :-

```
+ export GO=/usr/local/go/bin/go
+ GO=/usr/local/go/bin/go
+ export 'ldflags=-ldflags="-X main.level=info"'
+ ldflags='-ldflags="-X main.level=info"'
+ CMD='/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags="-X main.level=info" cmd/adapter/*'
+ echo /usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter '-ldflags="-X' 'main.level=info"' 'cmd/adapter/*'
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags="-X main.level=info" cmd/adapter/*
+ /usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter '-ldflags="-X' 'main.level=info"' 'cmd/adapter/*'
invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
usage: go build [-o output] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Until now I tried using different double quote(") escaping techniques also tried `$ldflags` and `"$ldflags"` but gets the same output.

**Update 1 :-**
Tried below option but still not working :-

```
ldflags=(-ldflags="-X main.level=info")
${ldflags[@]}
```

Debug output for above trial is as follow :-

```
+ mkdir -p bin
+ export GO=/usr/local/go/bin/go
+ GO=/usr/local/go/bin/go
+ ldflags=(-ldflags="-X main.level=info")
+ export ldflags
+ CMD='/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags=-X main.level=info cmd/adapter/*'
+ echo /usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags=-X main.level=info 'cmd/adapter/*'
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags=-X main.level=info cmd/adapter/*
+ /usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags=-X main.level=info 'cmd/adapter/*'
malformed import path "main.level=info": invalid char '='
malformed import path "cmd/adapter/*": invalid char '*'
```

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Don't export variables that do not need to be exported.

Comment: It might help to understand why your initial command is the same as: `/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags=-X\ main.level=info` and is also the same as `/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags=-"X ma"in.level=info`.

Answer (score 1):

*but fails from bash script* ....

Your commands are not identical. In the first version (which you claim to work), you write

```
/usr/local/go/bin/go build -o bin/adapter -ldflags="-X main.level=info" cmd/adapter/*
```

which means that the 4th parameter to `go` (argv[4] in C-terminology) becomes (after the shell deals with the quotes)

> -ldflags=-X main.level=info

In your script, we can see from the trace that this parameter is pased as

> -ldflags="-X

which means that we have an undesired double quote, and *main.level=info* is missing (this goes into the next parameter).

I would in your case define the parameters in an array
the way `go` wants to see them, i.e.

```
pars=(build -o bin/adapter '-ldflags=-X main.level=info' cmd/adapter/*)
```

and run them like this:

```
echo Running $GO "${pars[@]}" ...
"$GO" "${pars[@]}"
```

Comment: I want command to run exactly as it runs on terminal. In you response double quotes are missing.

Comment: In the way you run the command from the terminal, `go` also does not see any double quotes, and since you claim that this would work, of course I omitted them. BTW, did you actually tray my solution? If you did and it does not work, also include the trace (set -x) from my suggestion in your question.